# Vue/Vuetify - How to loop through array of strings and call each function inside an object?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an array of validation rules:

```
FieldValidationRules: ["isRequired", "isMinLength"]
```

My input component has an object which contains multiple rule functions:

```
  rules: {
    isRequired: (value) => !!value || "required",
    isMinLength: (value) => value.length >= 2 || "Must be at least 2 chars",
    isNotRequired: () => true,
  },
```

I'm currently looping through the FieldValidationRules array, assigning each value as a string. I want to use the returned string to target 1 or more keys inside the rules object. Unfortunately only the last rule (isMinLength) seems to be working. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ question.Text }}</p>
    <v-text-field
      dense
      outlined
      hide-details="auto"
      v-model="question.Value"
      :rules="[rules[getRules]]"
    ></v-text-field>
    {{ getRules }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputBase",
  props: {
    question: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        isRequired: (value) => !!value || "required",
        isMinLength: (value) => value.length >= 2 || "Must be at least 2 chars",
        isNotRequired: () => true,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getRules() {
      let rule = "";

      this.question.FieldValidationRules.forEach((currentRule) => {
        rule = currentRule;
      });

      return rule;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Comment: I'm not directly answering to your question, but in your case I strongly recommend you to rather use a validation module such as vee-validate ([v4 for vue3](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) or [v3 for vue2](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3)) or [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/). Those tools are built for Vue and will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working hope this is helpful to someone.

my solution is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ question.Text }}</p>
    <v-text-field
      dense
      outlined
      hide-details="auto"
      v-model="question.Value"
      :rules="getRules"
    ></v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputBase",
  props: {
    question: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        isRequired: (value) => !!value || `${this.question.Text} required`,
        isMinLength: (value) =>
          value.length >= 2 || `${this.question.Text} must be at least 2 chars`,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getRules() {
      if (!this.question.FieldValidationRules) {
        return;
      }
      return this.question.FieldValidationRules.map((rule) => {
        // if the rules object has a key matching the item variable
        // return the function assigned to that key else return true
        // setting true means that the validation will always pass
        return this.rules[rule] || true;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```